# convert .py file into .exe using unix

Tags: python

I was using c shell of unix. I have created a script in python with file extension `.py`.
Now I want to convert this `.py` file into an `.exe` file in unix's c shell.
I found that `py2exe` package will not work for csh, but there is `freeze.py` which I could use to convert says Google.
But I am unable to use this in my case. When I use `python freeze.py hello.py`  it raises an error: `freeze.py not found`
Is there any other way to it in UNIX.

Comment: may I know the reason for downvoting...

Comment: did you look up freeze? did you actually install it? the downvote might be from someone who thought you didn't do your homework first before asking. to me it sounds like you're just lost. look around some more and then come back.

Comment: So you're trying to build a Windows .exe executable on a unix system?

Comment: @martineau That is what cross-compiling about.

Comment: @BasicWolf: I know that -- was just trying to make sure that's what the OP had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is "No". Although there is an option: use WINE with [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

> PyInstaller is a program that converts (packages) Python programs into
>   stand-alone executables, under Windows, Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris and
>   AIX. Its main advantages over similar tools are that PyInstaller works
>   with any version of Python since 2.2, it builds smaller executables
>   thanks to transparent compression, it is fully multi-platform, and use
>   the OS support to load the dynamic libraries, thus ensuring full
>   compatibility.

Comment: This page: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Py2Exe specifically states that Py2exe doesn't work with Wine (it produces faulty executables). It also discusses other possibilities, such as PyInstaller and freeze.

Comment: I meant PyInstaller with WINE. That is recommented in its FAQ.